# Dynamically creating Jquery selectors / possible Jquery bug

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically creating a jquery selector, which will select an element or a group of elements by class, id, name, or value. My selector looks like this:

```
$("["+type+"="+value+"]")......
```

which works great..... most of the time.

However, when I place this selector in a function, it ceases to work properly.

e.g. this doesn't work (even if I hard code it)

```
$("[class=thisclass]").....
```

but this DOES work

```
$(".thisclass").....
```

obviously, I *could* just check if the type is class, and use the decimal method, but I would rather keep the selecting method consistent.

Is this a Jquery bug? or am I missing something?

Comment: You say it doesn't work when you place it in a function but then you don't show your function or how you're calling it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `[class=abc]` will only match an element with the class "abc" and not "abc def", consider this:

```
<div class="abc def" />
<div class="abc" />
```

jQuery

```
$('.abc'); // will match both div's
$('[class=abc]'); // will only match the 2. div
```

You could use the [tilde attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/):

```
// Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word, delimited by spaces. 
$('[class~=abc]');  // will match both div's
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes around your value:

```
$("["+type+"='"+value+"']")
```

Will become

```
$("[class='thisclass']")
```

Comment: When that is said the above will only match if the `class="thisclass"` and not if `class="thisclass anotherclass"`. While `.thisclass` will match both.

Comment: @dev-null I reread the question and don't see that as a requirement listed. Did I miss something?

Comment: @dev-null - that was the answer! Seems like a JQuery bug to me - class="thisclass" should match ALL members of the class!  ... but I can see why you would not always want it that way.

Comment: @asdf - I am aware that adding quotes is "kosher". However, they are not entirely necessary. It actually works WITHOUT the quotes the same as WITH the quotes -- with the exception of multiple class names. In my case, I only want to match a single class.

Comment: @SkeetsO'Reilly I added an answer to clarify how this works.